# South and Django - error on migration of unique=True

Tags: django, migration, django-south

I have tried to change field's property - from unique=False to unique=True
and I'm getting the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "xxx_fieldname_key"
DETAIL:  Key (fieldname)=() is duplicated.
```

Any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the field you're trying to make unique already has records with duplicate value on `fieldname`. Check in your database if it's the case. Post your model code and full error message if not.